# Compare cell with a previous cell in the column and update the cell with new value based on the difference

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, macros

```
Sub Update_cell()

Dim counter As Integer
For counter = 7 To 606
   If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value > (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value)
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value - 1 * (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value)
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 13).Value = -1 * (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value)
   End If
   If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value < (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value = (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value)
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value - 1 * (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value)
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 13).Value = -1 * (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value)
   End If
   If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value <= (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value) And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value >= (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value - Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 4).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value
   End If
   Next counter
End Sub
```

Above is my code which I am using to update a cell based on how far it is from the previous cell. In the beginning, I got an error saying "The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type". I deleted the chart which was already present and now I get the error saying "Subscript out of range, Runtime error 9". When I try to debug, it highlights the first If statement.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: usually this means that Sheet1 does not exist.  Is it named something else?

Comment: @ScottCraner I'd post that as an answer mate, definitely looks to be the root cause

Comment: Thank you very much  @ScottCraner. Your answer was very helpful. I don't know why I missed such a small detail. I should get more careful with experience. I am new to VBA programming.

Answer (score 0):

@Scott Craner provided an answer to my question in the comments section. I was using Sheet1 as the sheet name instead of the actual name of the sheet. Should be more careful next time.

Thanks again Scott!